# How to get feedback from saga handler using NServiceBus Acceptance Testing

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus, xunit, acceptance-testing

**Background**

I have written a test that makes sure that the command that should start my saga effectively creates the saga and that it's handler code can be executed:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Can_Start_Saga_And_Execute_Handler()
{
    var result = await Scenario
        .Define<Context>()
        .WithEndpoint<Endpoint>(b => b.When(session =>
            {
                return session.SendLocal(new SagaStarter());
            })
        )
        .Done(context => context.IsRequested)
        .Run(Testing.MaxRunTime);

    result.IsRequested.ShouldBeTrue();
}
```

Where Context is:

```
class Context : ScenarioContext
{
    public bool IsRequested { get; set; }
}
```

**So**

If I have a handler in my saga definition like so:

```
public async Task Handle(SagaStarter message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
    await StuffToDo();
}
```

> How can I ensure that the `IsRequested` property, defined in
>   `Context`, is set to true from within the saga?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found *a* solution, adding an extra message handler in the test like so:

```
public class TestHandler : IHandleMessages<SagaStarter>
{
    private Context _testContext;

    public TestHandler(Context testContext)
    {
        _testContext = testContext;
    }

    public Task Handle(SagaStarter message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        _testContext.IsRequested= true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The `Context` parameter is inserted through [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).